# BigQuery stream inserts: Maximum allowed row size exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, streaming

While using [BigQuery stream insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery), specifically, the [tabledata.insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) method, I got errors saying `Maximum allowed row size exceeded`. It looks like the maximum row size allowed is only 1MB when using stream inserts (confirmed by [this quota page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaminginserts)).

```
error message: [{
    "index": 13,
    "errors": [{
        "reason": "invalid",
        "location": "",
        "debugInfo": "",
        "message": "Maximum allowed row size exceeded. Allowed: 1048576 Row size: 1383661"
    }]
```

How do one get around this situation  - if I really need streaming inserts?

Comment: "How do one get around this situation" -> how hard would it be to limit rows to 1MB?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa It's used in ETL: I'm dumping Datastore entity dicts into BQ.  Some large ones are over 1M. I may be able to shrink the dicts a little bit but I'd rather keep them as complete as possible.

Comment: you may want to store them in a separate table, then. you don't want heavy rows because you're costs will be high when a lot of rows need to be scanned during queries. The limit is there for a good reason, don't try to "get around it". Re-think your design instead.

Comment: if still interested, you can vote/star https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159363776

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the best approach to address this issue is changing the code to break down the size.

Another way is contacting the [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) to request an increase, for example you can ask for doubling the limit. Keep in mind that it might or might not be granted. To request an increase, it is needed to upgrade your account as indicated in the [Program Coverage for Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) period or even better having a support package.